# When I host 2 apps (Web API and Blazor server) on Windows Server 2019, the API localhost port refuses to connect to SQL Server database on IIS

Tags: sql-server, blazor-server-side, minimal-apis

When I publish both projects to a local Windows IIS, they both run smoothly, but when I publish to Windows Server 2019, I get an error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.(localhost: 7112)

Please help me - how should I configure my `web.config` after publishing to the live server?

I enabled websockets on both apps `program.cs`, I even opened the apps ports on the firewall, it's  my first time deploying to a real live server, I'm not sure what I left behind

Comment: Only one process at a time can open a particular socket for listening to receive network connections. It seems like both your projects are attempting to listen on `127.0.0.1:7112` at the same time. Probably when you're debugging locally you're using IIS Express and the launchSettings.json files in each project have `$.iisSettings.iisExpress.applicationUrl` configured to use different ports.

Comment: Ok thank you how may I overcome this issue